# Cannot successfully prepare iOS

Tags: ios, cocoapods, nativescript, nativescript-vue, material-components

I cannot seem to get the `tns prepare ios` command to work since upgrading from `"tns-core-modules": "6.2.1"` to `"tns-core-modules": "^6.3.2"`. I receive the following message:

> Webpack compilation complete.
>
> Installing pods...
>
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
>   "MaterialComponents/Tabs":   In Podfile:
>       MaterialComponents/Tabs (~> 92.3)
>
> ```
> MaterialComponents/Tabs (~> 94.5)
> ```
>
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies:
>   `MaterialComponents/Tabs (~> 92.3), MaterialComponents/Tabs (~>
>   94.5)`.
>
> You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with
>   `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.  * mistyped the
>   name or version.  * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec
>   to your Podfile.
>
> [!] There are duplicate dependencies on `MaterialComponents/Tabs` in
>   `Podfile`:
>
> - MaterialComponents/Tabs (~> 92.3)
> - MaterialComponents/Tabs (~> 94.5) 'pod install' command failed. For more information on resolving CocoaPod issues in NativeScript read.

I have tried running `pod repo update` and `pod install --repo-update` with no success. I'm running this with xCode 10.1 on macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra).

**package.json**

```
{
    "description": "xxxx",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "readme": "xxxxx",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "xxxxxx",
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "6.2.0"
        },
        "tns-ios": {
            "version": "6.3.0"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nativescript/core": "6.2.1",
        "@nativescript/theme": "2.2.0",
        "@progress-nativechat/nativescript-nativechat": "2.0.4",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "kinvey-nativescript-sdk": "4.2.5",
        "nativescript-accelerometer": "3.0.0",
        "nativescript-background-http": "4.2.1",
        "nativescript-camera": "4.5.0",
        "nativescript-fonticon": "^2.0.0",
        "nativescript-geolocation": "5.1.0",
        "nativescript-image": "2.2.5",
        "nativescript-imagepicker": "7.1.0",
        "nativescript-intl": "3.0.0",
        "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.5.1",
        "nativescript-purchase": "^2.0.13",
        "nativescript-social-share": "1.5.2",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.6",
        "nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "6.0.0",
        "nativescript-ui-calendar": "6.0.0",
        "nativescript-ui-chart": "7.0.0",
        "nativescript-ui-dataform": "6.0.0",
        "nativescript-ui-gauge": "6.0.0",
        "nativescript-ui-listview": "8.0.1",
        "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "8.0.0",
        "nativescript-vue": "2.4.0",
        "tns-core-modules": "^6.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.6.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
        "babel-types": "6.26.0",
        "babylon": "6.18.0",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
        "css-hot-loader": "^1.4.2",
        "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "lazy": "1.0.11",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
        "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.3.0",
        "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
        "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.9.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "tns-platform-declarations": "6.2.1",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "~1.2.7",
        "vue-loader": "^15.8.3",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~2.13.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `package.json`?

Comment: Sure. I have added as part of my question.

Comment: @Manoj any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, removing and adding again the IOS platform resolved it.